# PHP - Get all Values with Key X of multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, foreach

I've got an array with some arrays in it.

I am trying to group all values of all arrays with (for example) the key [0] in one group.

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Haus
            [1] => Baum
            [2] => Stern
            [3] => Wache
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => What
            [1] => Ever
            [2] => Damn
            [3] => Hard
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2. UG
            [1] => 1. UG
            [2] => EG
            [3] => 1. OG
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Auffahrt
            [1] => Abfahrt
            [2] => Einfahrt
            [3] => Ausfahrt
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24 Monate
            [1] => 12 Monate
            [2] => 12 Monate
            [3] => 24 Monate
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem eins
            [1] => Lorem zwei
            [2] => Lorem drei
            [3] => Lorem vier
        )

)
```

Im trying to do this because I want to echo e.g.

You said "Haus, What, 2. UG, Auffahrt, 24 Monate and Lorem eins" so all Values with the key [0] but I need the rest, too.

I hope my question is understandable,
greetings.

Comment: Can't yoyu simply iterate over all arrays and check for that key?

Comment: You probably want array_column: http://www.php.net/array_column

Comment: @arkascha I'm not really experienced in PHP, I've tried many different things already but nothing seemed to work. You've got an idea that I can play around with?

Comment: "nothing seemd to work" never helped anyone with any task. What does that mean? Where are your attempts? We can only help with them if you show them!

Comment: Thanks for the input arkascha, I'll try to do that next time since jbafford s answer already provided the result I seeked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone still needs an answer to this,

jbafford's comment brought me to this solution:

```
$col = array_column($daten, 0);
print_r($col);
```

[Solution](http://php.net/array_column/)